# Is it faster to buy in bulk rather than individually?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

In AdVenture Capitalist you can buy megatickets using megabucks.

Is it faster to buy a bulk of 10 tickets, or would it be faster to                                          complete if I bought and used one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would certainly be faster to buy them one by one, but you can only get 90 mega-bucks on each planet and 2 of 3 planets have 10 businesses, so if you want to boost everything, you would need to buy in bulk.

Comment: FOR NOW, UNTIL EARTH EXPANDS
btw, I don't wanna boost everything, just win earth.
Also, you can buy more than 90. Forget my other question.